# Install GNU "script" command on Mac

Tags: macos, bash, homebrew, gnu

I have a Mac. I would like to use the <s>GNU</s> `script` that comes with CentOS as it is more full-featured than the <s>BSD</s> Mac version. Specifically, `man script` on a CentOS box gives:

> ```
>    -c, --command command
>           Run the command rather than an interactive shell.  This makes it easy  for  a  script  to
>           capture the output of a program that behaves differently when its stdout is not a tty.
> ```

and the version on my Mac has no such option. I want to [see the output of my command while pretending to be a tty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401002/how-to-trick-an-application-into-thinking-its-stdout-is-a-terminal-not-a-pipe), and this is the only way I know how to do that.

I have brew, and have installed a bunch of GNU versions of utilities (`grep findutils coreutils gawk gnu-sed gnu-tar gnu-indent gnu-getopt gnutls`), and none of these seem to provide `script`.

I tried searching through Homebrew formulae, but unsurprisingly, a lot of packages mention the word "script", so I could have easily missed it.

**Edit**: based on comments, I'm not sure there is a *GNU* `script`, but there is certainly another version around that my Mac does not have. `script --version` returns 2.x.x on CentOS 7 and "illegal argument" on Mac.

Also from comments, it sounds like `util-linux` provides `script`, but the brew version does not have a `script` command that I could find:

```bsh
brew install util-linx
cd $(brew --prefix)/opt/util-linux
find . -name "script"  # returns nothing
```

Comment: Well, on my Ubuntu `script` comes from the `bsdutils` package, so there wouldn't be a GNU `script`. `script --version` says `script from util-linux 2.34` so this version could be the difference.

Comment: `man script` on my mac displays a date of "December 4, 2013 " and no version that I can see (`script --version` returns "illegal option"). `man script` on my CentOS displays a date of "September 2011", and `script --version` returns `2.23.2`.

Comment: Is this it? [`util-linux`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/util-linux.rb)

Comment: @guest, I tried installing that but it did not provide `script`; I updated my question.

Comment: I'd suggest to go the other way: track down the source code and see if goes in a package (at worst you can recompile it...).

Comment: The brew package util-linux does refer to the GitHub repo util-linux/util-linux, which *does* contain `script`. However, that same package reports that `script` as only supported in Linux. Using `strings` on MacOS' `script` and some googling led me to the GitHub repo apple-oss-distributions/shell_cmds/tree/shell_cmds-278. And seems to come from FreeBSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to trick command to think stdout is TTY, you can use `unbuffer` instead. It is part of `expect` brew formulae.

```
brew install expect
unbuffer -p <COMMAND_TO_TRICK>
```

Example:

```
echo "colorme" | unbuffer -p grep --color=auto colorme | cat
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked about script, and this is most likely off topic. However if you're recording something to play back later with timing this might be useful to you.

As I used script primarily to record what was happening with timings so I could play it back, almost never for just a list of commands. I switched to using asciinema for this which can be installed via brew. It has ways to easily play back reducing the idle times, overall speed adjustments, and works in the browser and shell.

Comment: I am most interested in grabbing the raw output, since lots of commands will change their output to remove coloring when being piped elsewhere. Will asciinema let me save the raw command output somewhere and trick the commands into thinking they're outputting directly to a TTY?